# How do I create an interactive I/O GUI for my Java project?

Tags: java, user-interface

Okay, so I've gotten to the point where I am starting to write code that's actually practical and reduces a good chunk of my work load.  However, how do I package it into a user friendly self contained interface for people to use, that also provides an option for user's input and produces an output?  I can't very well tell people to download Eclipse and compile/run the code. So what's the next step for putting together an actual application?

Comment: Do you mean packaging like maven?

Comment: Go to File -> export -> java -> jar -> select runnable jar

Comment: Also see [**packaging programs in jars**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html). There you will see how create executable jars.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean packaging in terms of our java interface (API) or an actual GUI as the answers are a bit mixed up. I read it as API (i.e. build a jar using jar, Eclipse [or other IDE], ant or maven) but there's a case for reading your question as how to build a GUI (using Swing, EMF, HTML/JSP/JSF/GWT, etc)

Comment: @wmorrison365:  I want to make my code work for someone who doesn't have any coding knowledge, simply by being prompted for input and then spitting back a result.  So whatever is required to do that.  I'm looking into swing right now.

Comment: If you want user interaction, then Swing, SWT, JavaFX is definitely the way to go, since simply packaging your Java code without a GUI won't do anything for the user experience.

Comment: @nobacode I'm getting started with SWT.  Does any one (SWT, Java FX, Swing), offer a benefit over the others?  Or do they all do thew same thing, just done with different libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I started creating GUIs in Java, one of the best places that I found to have most up-to-date information were Oracle's Java tutorials.  You may create GUI with JavaFX or Swing - the choice will be up to you.  I personally started with Swing because it was easier for me to understand, but after reading up on both and doing a few beginner tutorials you should be able to make a clear choice.

Swing Tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

JavaFX Tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/index.html

A fantastic feature on Oracle's website is the [Learning Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html) portion, which allows you to jump into appropriate tutorial environment based on your current knowledge.  One of the sections is **"Cherish the Client?"**, which covers things such as graphics and graphical user interfaces.

What I liked about the Swing tutorials, when I was doing them, was the fact that they did a fantastic job of providing illustrations of the outcomes along with an amazing amount of sample code.  Great example of that is the explanation of [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), which makes it easy for a beginner to understand the concepts through visual demonstrations.  I seriously wish MSDN had this.  As I'm getting better with C# and .NET, I find that it's easier to understand newer concepts, but it was a pain to start out (for me).

Due to the fantastic documentation that Oracle provides, I was able to create a personnel management program with one month of prior java experience through college and one semester of C++ prior to that.  Experiences could vary from an individual to an individual, but I found that Oracle's documentation is phenomenal. You can expect the same level of detail and illustration from JavaFX tutorials, so don't be intimidated by either one - just give both a try and pick what fits your style.

Note that you can integrate JavaFX into Swing, so you can learn both and benefit from it.

If Eclipse is your choice of IDE, then SWT would probably work well for you.  You may find an extensive guide for SWT with Eclipse here:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html

To view the available SWT widgets go here:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/

As you see, SWT offers a fairly modern design option.

I would highly suggest to download their **[examples](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php)** and go through the code, so that you can get an overview of what you are to expect prior to diving in and committing your time to it.  They also have, very similarly to Oracle's tutorials, an **[enormously wide range of code snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)** for different tasks.  That should help you get started.

Lastly, I'd like to make a note of a great website that has boosted my knowledge by unimaginable amounts and is one of the reasons why I was able to get a programming job with eight months of prior programming experience from college (so, console programs and little boxes in Java classes) - [Plurasight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/).  Check out their full library.  If you're a student, you can get six months of free content or you can do a trial before you commit.  They have a very good Java section and I **highly** recommend them. *Disclaimer: I don't work for them, I don't know anyone operating that website/company, I have no vested interest in them beyond as a happy customer.*

Comment: @Nubacode thanks do much. This is an extremely useful resource. The Swing tutorial uses the netbeans IDE. I'm using eclipse. Are they similar enough that I could use that tutorial? Or should I look god a swing tutorial that uses eclipse?

Comment: @StuartKuredjian Any IDE will do the job. Project setups might differ slightly, but you are learning concepts - which is the important part. By the way, Thyne made a good point that SWT works with Eclipse. Some of the Oracle tutorials cover SWT.  Check out my updated answer for SWT options.

Comment: I like Vogella tutorials (and he's quick to reply if you spot an issue).

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of GUI tutorials on YouTube. You can create "Runnable JAR file" from Eclipse.  File --> Export -->  Runnable JAR file. With this file, you can just click on the icon to run your program.

Answer (score 3):

For Java the standard way to package an executable program is to create a JAR file. Basically it is all of the compiled .class files, and any resource files you need, as well as some Manifest information all packed together into a single file. In order to be executable, the manifest must specify what the main class is. Eclipse will do this for you when you export a JAR for a project.

However, on some systems (such as linux if not configured to run jars directly), the jar must be explicitly run from java with a command like

```
java -jar myprogram.jar
```

You can of course make a simple script that runs that command, and can also have the script set environment variables if so desired.

As for the GUI, you will need to decide on a GUI toolkit to use. Swing comes with Java by default, but in my opinion is kind of ugly. There is also SWT, which is what eclipse uses. And many other toolkits have Java bindings, including Wx, Qt, Gtk, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends from your application and your desires. if you want to get simple GUI with easy implementation in your `web application` you should use `Apache Wicket`. It is very easy implementation and this has integration with `Spring Security`. Plain swt components and HTML is the easiest way to make GUI and all of this, you can find in `Apache Wicket`. This GUI will be ok for small part of your whole system, but I do not recommend to use it for huge GUI.